# sharing windows 7 cable internet connection to nexus 4 via WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-4, internet, windows

I am connected to the internet via an ethernet cable on my laptop pc. I want to share my PC's internet connection with my Nexus 4(Android 4.4.2).

I have created an ad-hoc network on my windows 7 pc but this network doesn't display in the available networks on my Nexus 4.

How can I share my PC's internet connection with my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Connectify Hotspot Free. It have 90min limited uptime and some adds. I had same problem with sharing internet connection via Windows 7 ad-hoc so I tried a some tools to share internet but only Connectify worked well in my case.

Answer (score 0):

there are some ways to reverse tether, and the simplest one is to use Connectify. Free version is limited in uptime, the full version has no restrictions. It's not even hard to convince the program to allow all functions, btw.